# Vim autocompletion in terminal mode

Tags: vim

When in insert mode, a list of completion candidates can be shown by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> (for insert mode completion), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (for Omni completion when `omnifunc` is set). However, these keybindings do not work in terminal mode (`:term`).

Question: how can I get a list of completion candidates when in terminal mode? I was expecting to be able to make vim display completion candidates like `grep`, `kill`, `cd`, `python3`, and file paths like `/home/user/Desktop`, `/home/user/Documents`, etc.

I am using vim 8.0.

Comment: Both are "insert mode completion". `<C-n>` is "keyword completion".

Answer (score 0):

In this case a terminal is shown in vim, so your input goes to the terminal not to vim. That means we have to use the completion your terminal offers you. `tab` should be working like always, for a vim style completion you could add that to your `.inputrc`:

```
# cycle forward
Control-n: menu-complete
# cycle backward
Control-p: menu-complete-backward
```

Comment: I already have `tab` completion in my shell. I wanted to use native completion in vim to get as-you-type autosuggestion lists for the terminal (something similar to what can be achieved with Emacs' eshell with company mode).

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that. But with the above code you can at least cycle between the possible completions. Hope somebody will be able to help you more

Comment: tab deosn't work like a normal shell. It changes the line
I guess I didn't have this problem with neovim. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A `:terminal` is just a view into an interactive shell (or another command started by or in place of the shell). Vim offers some integration (pass on typed keys, show output), but **it's the shell who's running the show**.

As Vim does not know what's going on there (you could have launched a command where completions for file system paths or commands, as you've suggested, would not make any sense; you could have `ssh`'d into another system that does not have `python3` installed), it cannot and should not offer you these things. Instead, as others have already commented, this is the job of the shell (and most of them provide completion, some (like Bash) even very powerful and extensible ones that go far beyond your suggestions) or the command that is running.